# Flipping image not working on iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios10

I am facing weird issue while flipping Image in `iOS 10`

Here is my code.

```
uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:ciImage];
flippedImg = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage scale:uiImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
captureImgView.image = flippedImg;
```

I am taking one `ciImage` and getting it into `uiImage`.
then flipping that `UIImage`.
this code works fine on all iOS version, lower than 10.
but not working on 10 and above.

I tried all Orientations,

```
UIImageOrientationUpMirrored
UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored
UIImageOrientationUp
UIImageOrientationRight
UIImageOrientationDown
UIImageOrientationLeft
UIImageOrientationDownMirrored
UIImageOrientationRightMirrored
```

But nothing work.

I am taking selfie from front camera and attaching that selfie to `UIImageView`.
I don't want to attach flipped image taken from front camera.
I want orignal image here.

Please guide me for same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution by my own.
What I did, 
I checked for iOS10 version of system,
captured the image from front camera, converted from `CIImage` to `UIImage` and placed it on the `UIImageView`.
Once I placed it on `UIImageView`,
I rotate the `UIImageView` using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` to fit in appropriate position and place.

here is the sample code.

```
NSString *systemVersion = [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion;
captureImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
if([systemVersion floatValue] < 10.0)
{
    uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:ciImage];
    flippedImg = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage scale:uiImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
    captureImgView.image = flippedImg;
    captureImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
}
else
{
    uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:ciImage];
    flippedImg = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage scale:uiImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
    captureImgView.image = uiImage;
    captureImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation ((M_PI * 270 / 180.0));
 }
```

Comment: I just flipped the image, so basically what I did, captured the image then iOS10 was flipping it automatically, I checked for iOS version and if it is > iOS10 then again I flipped it. so basically for iOS10 image is getting flipped twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed something. In my code it's working fine...

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgOriginal;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgFlipped;

@end

#pragma mark - UIImagePicker delegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *uiImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    CGImageRef cgImage = uiImage.CGImage;
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    UIImage *flippedImg = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage scale:uiImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];

    _imgOriginal.image = uiImage;
    _imgFlipped.image = flippedImg;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here output :

[image: Flip_Image]

In iOS 10, it will be like :

```
#pragma mark - UIImagePicker delegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *uiImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     CGImageRef cgImage = uiImage.CGImage;
    //CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    //UIImage *flippedImg = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage scale:uiImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    UIImage *flippedImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:uiImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];

    _imgOriginal.image = uiImage;
    _imgFlipped.image = flippedImg;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: yes, I am getting this one only. but I don't want to flip the image. I want to show as it is. and that to captured from front camera. Image placed directly over UIImageView working at my end too...

Comment: Then use original image directly.... 


`UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall1.png"];
_imgOriginal.image = uiImage;`

Comment: I am capturing image from front camera. not direct image

Comment: I am taking selfie from front camera and then showing it on UIImageView. but while showing it on UIImageView it shows flipped image but I don't want to flip the image taken from front camera. I want to show image as it is. The code that I have written is working well for iOS version lower than 10 but not working well on iOS 10